# NextJS build - deopted into client-side rendering (deep)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

The message is very clear, deopted into client-side rendering.
The strange thing is that each build brings different results.

Example.
Sometimes I get an error that the /checkout page itself is having a problem with client/server-side rendering.

```
....
"next": "^13.4.5",
"react": "^18.2.0",
....
```

Node version:

```
node -v
v21.1.0
```

```
> yarn lint
yarn run v1.22.10
$ next lint
✔ No ESLint warnings or errors
✨  Done in 3.42s.
```

next build

```
(node:17589) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Warning: For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'npm i sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
```

/checkout

```
import CheckoutTemplate from "@modules/checkout/templates"
import { Metadata } from "next"

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Checkout",
}

export default function Checkout() {
  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <CheckoutTemplate />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
import { CheckoutProvider } from "@lib/context/checkout-context"
import CheckoutForm from "./checkout-form"
import CheckoutSummary from "./checkout-summary"
import BreadCrumb from "@modules/cart/components/bread-crumb"
import AboveForm from "./above-form"

const CheckoutTemplate = () => {
  return (
    <CheckoutProvider>
      <BreadCrumb active="checkout" />
      <div className="page-content">
        <div className="container p-relative">
          <AboveForm />
          <div className="row mb-9">
            <div className="col-lg-7 pr-lg-4 mb-4">
              <CheckoutForm />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-5 mb-4 sticky-sidebar-wrapper">
              <CheckoutSummary />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </CheckoutProvider>
  )
}

export default CheckoutTemplate
```

The components inside this one have "use client;", is that a problem?

Comment: The `next build` output you posted contains no errors...

Comment: Hi @EliasSoares, I don't have build errors, just warning with deopted into client-side rendering

Comment: Post a warning you get as well